# Product Catalog Serialization

Tags: sitecore-commerce

I was trying to serialize Sitecore Commerce 9 Product catalog but it could not serialize automatically just after creating category/sellable item from BizFx (Sitecore Commerce) website.

Please can someone guide me how to serialize Sitecore Commerce 9 Product Catalog?

I don't want to create zip package to push Product Catalog from one environment to other.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't exist such a functionality in Sitecore Commerce.

The products (products,catalogs, categories) are persistent in Commerce Engine not in Sitecore.

Products,catalogs and categories from Sitecore are not real items, are virtual items which are shown in Content Editor using Commerce Engine Connect Catalog Provider. The provider is defined in: **Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.DataProvider.config**

```
<sitecore role:require="Standalone or ContentDelivery or ContentManagement">
    <dataProviders>
      <catalogProvider role:require="Standalone or ContentManagement" type="Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.Connect.DataProvider.CatalogDataProvider, Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.Connect">
        <targetDatabaseName>master</targetDatabaseName>
      </catalogProvider>
      <catalogProvider role:require="ContentDelivery" type="Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.Connect.DataProvider.CatalogDataProvider, Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.Connect">
        <targetDatabaseName>web</targetDatabaseName>
      </catalogProvider>
    </dataProviders>
```

You can serialize the items from a catalog but you can not import them into other system.

Comment: Thanks @Vlad for your response. So the only option left is to create a zip package and import into the other environments.

Answer (score 2):

We can use Postman tool to export the product catalog. It gives zip file. After that we can again use Postman to import the exported product catalog.

[image]